# How to add scroll bar to the table with fixed header row?

Tags: html, css, html-table, scrollbar

My table have too many columns and it overflows the page's 100% width. So I need to add a horizontal scroll bar to table.

But I also need to fix the header for vertical scroll bar when there are too many rows to scroll.

What is the correct way to accomplish it, using CSS and HTML?

First code is a CSS

```css
table .titleFormat{
                text-align: center;
                width:170px;
                font-size:14px;
           }
```

This is HTML code

```html
<div style="width: 400px;height:150px;overflow-x: auto;overflow-y: auto">
    <table id="example-basic" style="width: 100%;">

            <thead>
                <tr class="TitleHeader">
                    <th width="200px"><div class="titleFormat">A</div></th>
                    <th  width="100px"><div class="titleFormat">B</div></th>
                    <th width="100px"><div class="titleFormat">C</div></th>
                    <th width="100px"><div class="titleFormat">D</div></th>
                    <th width="100px"><div class="titleFormat">E</div></th>
                   </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>         
                <tr>
                    <td style=" text-align: left ">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                          1
                    </td>

                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <td style=" text-align: left ">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                          1
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style=" text-align: left ">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                          1
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style=" text-align: left ">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                          1
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style=" text-align: left ">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                          1
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style=" text-align: left ">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                          1
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style=" text-align: left ">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                            1
                    </td>
                    <td style=" text-align: center">
                          1
                    </td>

                </tr>

            </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `position:Sticky` Element on your th and set the table `position:relative` and that will do the job.

check below:

```css
table .titleFormat {
  text-align: center;
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#example-basic {
  position: relative;
}

#example-basic th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 400px;height:150px;overflow-x: auto;overflow-y: auto">
  <table id="example-basic" style="width: 100%;">

    <thead>
      <tr class="TitleHeader">
        <th width="200px">
          <div class="titleFormat">A</div>
        </th>
        <th width="100px">
          <div class="titleFormat">B</div>
        </th>
        <th width="100px">
          <div class="titleFormat">C</div>
        </th>
        <th width="100px">
          <div class="titleFormat">D</div>
        </th>
        <th width="100px">
          <div class="titleFormat">E</div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style=" text-align: left ">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style=" text-align: left ">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style=" text-align: left ">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style=" text-align: left ">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style=" text-align: left ">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style=" text-align: left ">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style=" text-align: left ">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>
        <td style=" text-align: center">
          1
        </td>

      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I need. I will try later in my project.Thanks!

Comment: Sorry，it is not very friendly and it will jitter when I scroll... Is there any bootstrap ways?

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/T9Bhm/7 you can set `height` for `tbody` and `scroll` to auto

Answer (score 0):

check this style
I hope you enjoy it

```
    table {
      text-align: left;
      position: relative;
      border-collapse: collapse; 
    }
    th, td {
      padding: 0.25rem;
    }
    tr th {
      background: red;
      color: white;
    }
    th {
      background: white;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0; /* Don't forget this, required for the stickiness */
      box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
```